# Implementing Function that Maps over Stream

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

I implemented the following function:

> the ruler function
>
> 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, . . .
>
> where the nth element in the stream (assuming the first element
> corresponds to n = 1) is the largest power of 2 which evenly
> divides n

I'm giving it a vague name in the event that students try to cheat and search for it.

```
foo :: Stream Integer
foo = streamMap f startAtOne
    where f x        = if (odd x) then 0 else g x 0
          g y acc    = if y == 0 then acc else g (y-2) (acc+1)
          startAtOne = streamFromSeed 1 (+1)
```

Here's the `streamFromSeed` function and the `Stream` data type.

`data Stream a = Stream (a, Stream a)`

```
streamMap :: (a -> b) -> Stream a -> Stream b
streamMap f (Stream (x, rest)) = Stream (f x, streamMap f rest)

-- Given a start value and function, generate a stream by applying fn to each Stream value
streamFromSeed :: a -> (a -> a) -> Stream a
streamFromSeed x f = Stream $ (x, streamFromSeed (f x) f)
```

Note that this *technically* is [homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/hw/06-laziness.pdf), but from 2013. I'm working on this material since Prof. Yorgey provides excellent lectures and homework assignments. I'm not in this class nor a student at the school.

Comment: Updated to include the missing function and problem statement. thanks for asking

Comment: I *strongly* recommend doing Exercise 6 from the homework, Yorgey isn't lying when he says it's very cool.

Comment: After I got help on multiplying and dividing streams, I just got the answer. I haven't yet digested the solution, but it's very sweet!

Answer (score 2):

- Since `streamMap` allows you to map over a stream, you can as well define a [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) instance for `Stream`. Actually, streams can also define an Applicative instance which zips two streams and also a Monad instance whose [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) computes the diagonal of a 2-dimensional stream.
- Your definition of `Stream` is slightly inefficient as it wraps the `(,)` constructor in another constructor `Stream`. You could:

  - make it a `newtype`, or
  - use the [`UNPACK`](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#id559199) pragma, or
  - define just a 2-argument constructor like `data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)`.
- Your solution deviates from the assignment that forbids any kind of divisibility testing. Function `odd` tests for divisibility by 2 and `g` implements (somewhat inefficiently) division by 2.
- Without the full code it's a bit hard to test/judge correctness, but I believe your implementation is not correct. In particular, I believe for *n=6* your code will yield 3, while the expected value is 1.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed a very important hint in the homework:

> *Hint*: define a function `interleaveStreams` which alternates the elements from two streams. Can you use this function to implement ruler in a clever way that does not have to do any divisibility testing?

Let's look at the first few terms:

```
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, . . .
```

Every other term is 0, so let's ignore those for the moment. That leaves us with

```
1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, . . .
```

Every other term is 1, so let's ignore those for the moment...

```
2, 3, 2, 4, ...
```

Every other term is 2, ... etc etc.

That gives us a strong hint that our function will look like this:

```
interleave (streamRepeat 0) (interleave (streamRepeat 1) (interleave (streamRepeat 2) ...))
```

Which should look familiar to you by now -- we can write this in terms of `foldr`!

As Petr pointed out, we can just define `Stream` as

```
data Stream a = Stream a (Stream a)
```

I'll put the rest of the solution behind a spoiler tag.

> ```
>  streamRepeat :: a -> Stream a
>  streamRepeat x = let s = Stream x s in s
>  
>  interleaveStreams :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
>  interleaveStreams (Stream x xs) ys = Stream x (interleaveStreams ys xs)
>  
>  ruler :: Stream Integer
>  ruler = foldr1 interleaveStreams (map streamRepeat [0..])
> ```
>
> Bonus question: why won't this definition work for our solution?
>
> ```
> interleaveStreams (Stream x xs) (Stream y ys) = Stream x (Stream y (interleaveStreams xs ys))
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I glimpsed at your solution, and then realized (as you point out) that `interleave (streamRepeat 0) ...` (if written ad infinitum) would solve this problem. I tried `ruler` without `foldr`, but I ran into a StackOverflow - https://gist.github.com/kevinmeredith/506aad8a13fca5a7e190. Could you please take a look at my `ruler` there? I don't want to look at your **spoiler** just yet!

Comment: @KevinMeredith I should have split the spoiler in two parts (you'll see why later). Think about why your definition of `interleave` won't play  nicely with `ruler'`. You'll need a different definition of `interleave`.

Comment: ahh. so your advice to me is to implement `interleave` with `foldr`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith no, try expanding out `ruler' 0`: `ruler' 0 = interleave (streamRepeat 0) (ruler' 1) = interleave (streamRepeat 0) (interleave (streamRepeat 1) (...))`. How will the outer `interleave` be evaluated? Sorry if that's not clear... I got stumped by this for a while too.